# PHP: PDO throws SQL Syntax Error with bound params

Tags: php, pdo

I've read many of the other questions related to this issue, but I simply can't get to find my mistake. Here's my statement:

```
INSERT INTO ventas (`bodegaid`, `clienteid`, `usuarioid`, `tipodepagoid`, `fecha`, `numfact`, `serie`)
VALUES (:bodegaid, :clienteid, :usuarioid, :tipodepagoid, :fecha, :numfact, :serie)
```

Then I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near ':bodegaid, :clienteid, :usuarioid, :tipodepagoid,
:fecha, :numfact, :serie)' at line 1
```

From what I've read, this can happen when you use a reserved word as the column but that's not my case (unless I missed one but I don't think so). The table and all the columns are correct.

Are there any other reasons that could cause this error? I'm almost sure this is not about a syntax error. I've been trying to fix this for hours and I think it's probably about a silly thing I'm missing out.

Here's my PHP function, I get the $new_item from POST parameters. I have also checked that they are correctly being sent from the form:

```
function doVenta(){
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $new_item = $app->request->post();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (`bodegaid`, `clienteid`, `usuarioid`, `tipodepagoid`, `fecha`, `numfact`, `serie`)
            VALUES (:bodegaid, :clienteid, :usuarioid, :tipodepagoid, :fecha, :numfact, :serie)";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql); 

        $columns = getColumns('ventas');

        foreach($new_item as $col => $val){
            $paramN = ":".$col;
            $stmt->bindValue($paramN, $val);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $db->lastInsertId();

        $db->commit();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo errorMsg($e->getMessage());
    }

    //echo json_encode($new_item);
}
```

And this is the connection method, I'm using PDO:

```
function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="root";
    $dbname="inventarios";

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

Comment: Did you call `prepare()` and `bindValue()` on all of those?

Comment: Can you show us the actual PHP code?

Comment: You are probably using mysql connect instead of PDO.

Comment: I updated the post with the code I'm using. The getColumns method brings the columns that the table uses (which are the ones being passed as parameters).

Comment: The `$val` you're binding isn't surround by quotes in `$stmt->bindValue($paramN, $val);` Look at the syntax in the *fine* manual.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Fine* is a "reserved" word; *for the ladies* ;-)

Comment: That's true Jay, I fixed it but still won't work. Actually, the exception is thrown after `$stmt = $db->query($sql);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$stmt = $db->query($sql);` <= nope. You were right. Should have used "prepare" instead of "query", just like you said. Question would have most likely been solved *23 mins ago* if OP had posted full code from the get-go.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! That is correct! But that makes me wonder why I used other 'prepared' statements successfully using `$db->query()`. I'll change them all now, don't know why they are working correctly.

Comment: `query()` is when you want to "query" and not perform an insert or update, or anything that would modify a table. @jrlainfiesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
```

Should be:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```